# What is '6n' ( 6n (logn+1)= 6nlogn+6n ) in analysis of merge sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

Number of operations required to implimented merge is :

::::::    6n (logn+1)= 6nlogn+6n.

logn+1 is the number of  levels in merge sort. What is 6n here?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a crude merge sort: two reads to compare two elements, one read and one write to copy the smaller element to a working array, then later another read and another write to copy elements back to the original array, for a total of 6 memory accesses per element (except for boundary cases like reaching the end of a run, in which case the remainder of the other run is just copied without compares). A more optimized merge sort avoids the copy back step by alternating the direction of merge depending on the merge pass if bottom up, or the recursion level if top down, reducing the 6 to a 4. If an element fits in a register, then after a compare, the element will be in a register and will not have to be re-read, reducing the 6 to a 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what mean by "what is 6n"? If you are asking about the complexity of your algorithm (merge sort), it can be reduced to nlog(n). You can ignore the the coefficients in your problem as they are negligible when accounting for big O complexity. When calculating nlog(n) + n, you can also ignore n as it will increase at a much slower rate than nlog(n). This leaves you with a complexity of nlog(n).